# Unable to locate namespace handler for schema namespace [http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic, xml-namespaces, hdiv

While deploying the application in weblogic server, i am getting below error -

> 2018-04-13 15:18:10,856 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.Context initialization
>   failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv] Offending
>   resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hdiv-config.xml]
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:390)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:50)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3155)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:672)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:54)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:170)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:124)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:181)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:97)
>     at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

This is  my hdiv-config -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:hdiv="http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv 
    http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv/hdiv.xsd">

    <hdiv:config excludedExtensions="css,png,jpg,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,js,mp4" errorPage="/jsp/hdivErrorPage.jsp">
        <hdiv:sessionExpired loginPage="/welcome.do" homePage="/"/>
        <hdiv:startPages method="get">/,/welcome.do,/login.do,/captcha.do</hdiv:startPages>
        <hdiv:startPages method="post">/j_spring_security_check</hdiv:startPages>
        <hdiv:startParameters>_HDIV_STATE_</hdiv:startParameters>
    </hdiv:config>

    <!-- Accepted pattern within the application for all editable parameters (generated from textbox and textarea) -->
    <hdiv:validation id="safeText">
        <hdiv:acceptedPattern><![CDATA[^[a-zA-Z0-9@.\-_]*$]]></hdiv:acceptedPattern>
    </hdiv:validation>

    <!-- Finally, it's necessary to define editable data validation list for 
        the application -->
    <hdiv:editableValidations>
        <hdiv:validationRule url="/secure/.*"></hdiv:validationRule>
        <hdiv:validationRule url="/safetext/.*" enableDefaults="false">safeText</hdiv:validationRule>
    </hdiv:editableValidations>
</beans>
```

**Note - Same deployment is working in Tomcat Server.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It seems hdiv-config-x.x.x.jar is not in the classpath.

The namespace (http://www.hdiv.org/schema/hdiv) is defined in this library

Comment: It is present in the classpath